# is there a maximum android.os.Message.obj size?

Tags: android

I'm using Messages to return the HTML/XML/etc. from my "Communicator" service to some Activity in my App.

This is working great at the moment - but I worry: How big can the HTML get before this system breaks down?

**note:** I checked the documentation at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html but I don't see any max size warnings.

Maybe someone has a personal experience to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How big can the HTML get before this system breaks down?

If you are using the `obj` public data member on `Message` for intra-app data exchange, the limit is available heap space.